# true/false question regarding inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am not sure regarding this question. i am supposed to decide if 2 claims are true,false or only one is correct.

i've solved it, but not sure it's correct. would appreciate your opinions.

1)let $W=sp({2x+1,x^2})$ be a subspace of $R_3[x]x$ with the inegral inner product in [0,1], so {40x^2-44x+9} is a basis for $W^\bot$.

2)let $w=sp{(1,i,1),(1+i,0,2)}$ be a subspace of $C^3$, so {(1+i,1,-1)} is a basis for $W^\bot$.

both are correct if i calculated right. both sp's are linearly indepenent and they do seem to create a basis for $W^\bot$ (scalar product of 0). what i got is okie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. It's straight forward calculation that verifies the given vectors belong to the given perpendicular components. Since each $W$ is of dimension $2$ (since they're spanned by $2$ linearly independent vectors), it follows that each $W^\perp$ is dimension $1$, so a single non-zero vector will span them.

Comment: thank you very much. just wanted to be sure